# Как получить данные от rest-api , если в качестве значения @PathVariable - используются русские символы или пробелы

Tags: java, json, rest

Есть rest api

```java
  @GetMapping("city/{town}")
    public TargetDto get(@PathVariable String town) {
        return targetReadService.readEntry(town);

    }
```

Такой код нормально отработает, если в качестве значения будет предано слово с русскими символами. Когда зарос делаю из браузера.

Такой код отработает, если будет запрос из браузера

```java
/**
     * That avoid ambiguity you need to apply a regular expression.
     *
     * @param login - string value (allows letters and symbols
     *              `.` and `-`)
     * @return - http status code if request have processed correctly
     */
    @GetMapping("/login/{login:[A-Za-z-.]+}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> isUserByLogin(@PathVariable String login) throws ResourceNotFoundException {

        return loginService.getUserByLoginForCredentials(login);
    }
```

Но вот код ниже выдает ошибку.???

```java
    private String getREsponse(String message){

        URL url = null;

        String urlString = "http://localhost:8080/api/city/" + message;

       try {
           URL url_new = new URL(urlString);
           HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url_new.openConnection();
           InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
           InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
           BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

           String line;
           while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
               System.out.println(line); // выводим содержимое файла на экран построчно
           }
           System.out.println(line);
       } catch (IOException e) {

        logger.info( ERR_PARSE_RESPONSE, e);
    }

        try {
            url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/api/city/" + message );
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            logger.info(ERR_GET_API, e);

        }

        Scanner in = null;
        try {

            in = new Scanner((InputStream) url.getContent());
        } catch (IOException e) {

            logger.info( ERR_PARSE_RESPONSE, e);
        }

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        while (in.hasNext()) {
            result.append(in.nextLine());
        }


        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Что за ошибка? Какой именно текст вы передаёте? Вы не можете просто так прилепить любую строку в URL `"http://localhost:8080/api/city/" + message` - чтобы такое сделать, надо сначала строку message пропустить через UrlEndoder (хз как о в java называется).

Comment: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:

Comment: это ответ на первый вопрос, что насчет второго вопроса?

Comment: Какой именно текст вы передаёте?  http://localhost:8080/api/city/moscow  vol или http://localhost:8080/api/city/истра

Comment: http://localhost:8080/api/city/moscow - это принимает и возвращает нормально